# Get Installer Log File Path InstallShield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I need to know the InstallShield Log file path which is setup in command line parameters when an install is invoked.
I hope there should be some property setup in installsheild which handles the log file path where msi installation logs are to be written.
I need to handle that in code, so If I get any kind of property which is set to maintain installation log file path, I can use that property through custom action and can use it in my code..

Thanks in Advance
Mohit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property [`MsiLogFileLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370321.aspx) has this information at run time (once the MSI begins logging) in Windows Installer 4.0 and later, but there are very few reasons to use it directly.

In particular, if you are trying to add a message to the log, you should prefer to use [`MsiProcessMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370354.aspx) with `INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO`, one of its wrappers such as the VB [`Session.Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371672.aspx), or a workaround such as changing a property (if you are trying to log from a ControlEvent DoAction).

Comment: is there any way we could grab misLogFileLocation before Windows Installer 4.0, and if not, can you provide a simple c# program which writes to log fiel with MsiProcessMessage??

I am very new to installShield, so sorry for the trouble, but your help is really very appreciated.